# iOS App keeps crashing when using an AdMob banner

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, admob

I'm making an iOS 8.0+ game using **Xcode 7.3.1**, **SpriteKit**, and **Swift**. My app keeps on crashing whenever I add the AdMob banner to it.

I've pretty much copied the banner code from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Here's a part of my code:

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate{

  @IBOutlet var bannerView: GADBannerView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {

        let skView = self.view as! SKView

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true


        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        skView.presentScene(scene)

        let request = GADRequest()
        bannerView.delegate = self
        bannerView.adUnitID = "(myAppID)"
        bannerView.rootViewController = self
        bannerView.loadRequest(request)


    }
  }
 }
```

It runs perfectly fine on any simulator, but it crashes the app on an actual device. I keep getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: <f0cdd52e 01000000>)'
 *** First throw call stack: (0x1820b659c 0x19280c0e4 0x181fa11f8 0x1000ed1f8 0x100bbce30 0x100bbcdf0 0x100bc7854 0x100bc0120 0x100bc975c 0x100bcaf18 0x19302d2e4 0x19302cfa8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException(lldb)
```

If I remove part of the code that deals with the banner ad, my app runs perfectly.

Any suggestions on what I can do to fix it? Also, this is my first time coding an app using Xcode.

Thanks!

Comment: don't set a container with a certain key to nil,  find the line it crashes on, and fix it.  E.G. dictionary["key"] = cheese  where cheese = nil  <-- not allowed

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Does that have something to do with valueForKey or something like that?

Comment: no, you are setting a key,  value for key is reading.

Comment: maybe the myAppID is what is breaking on you

Comment: @Knight0fDragon It isn't. I used my actual appID and it worked fine on a simulator. On a device? No.

Comment: does your GoogleService-Info.plist have the right info?

Comment: that shouldn't be your appID, that should be your google ad id

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I know. That's what I meant. The ad ID for the app.

Comment: @Andy It does. I downloaded it and it's the right info.

Comment: try this   `request.testDevices = [ "kGADSimulatorID","{Device UUID HERE}"];`

Comment: show a pic of the stack trace

Comment: @Knight0fDragon It works on a simulator whether I use or don't use request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID]

Comment: ok, why are we worried about simulator,  you are worried about your device here,  google allows it to work in simulator without it, it just yells at you in the console

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I tried it on my device with the device ID, but it still won't work.

Comment: then it is something in your delegate functions, or some other error

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yup, the problem IS the banner ad. I don't get the error when I get rid of the banner code. When I call '@IBOutlet var bannerView: GADBannerView!' it pretty much takes it as a nil value. Any solution to this?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I tried using an Exception pointer, but it isn't telling me exactly where the issue is. I still get that `*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: <507e5444 01000000>)` error.

Answer (score 0):

It took a while, but I figured it out. I found out that the **Google Mobile Ads SDK** framework was the problem. Version 7.9.1 doesn't seem to work on iOS 8.0, but works well on iOS 9. I'm guessing that's why it didn't run well on my device, since I was running iOS 8 with SDK 7.9.1. With earlier versions such as 7.8.0, ads can run easily on iOS 8 devices.